# How check a password from a Meteor user in PHP

Tags: php, meteor, passwords, bcrypt

I need check a password generated from meteor using PHP

This is an example of password

> password: 123
>
> hash: $2a$10$MuXVnJFQ0kE1IB/RUfUoPuJJ8QJVkqChPwlgD6hnmkWclxGbpcQG6

I try using this php code, but I did not succeed

```
// show false
var_dump(password_verify("123", '$2a$10$MuXVnJFQ0kE1IB/RUfUoPuJJ8QJVkqChPwlgD6hnmkWclxGbpcQG6'));

// show false too
var_dump(crypt("123", '$2a$10$MuXVnJFQ0kE1IB/RUfUoPuJJ8QJVkqChPwlgD6hnmkWclxGbpcQG6') === '$2a$10$MuXVnJFQ0kE1IB/RUfUoPuJJ8QJVkqChPwlgD6hnmkWclxGbpcQG6');
```

How can I check this password outside Meteor?

Comment: Try `hash("sha256", "123") === '$2a$10$MuXVnJFQ0kE1IB/RUfUoPuJJ8QJVkqChPwlgD6hnmkWclxGbpcQG6'`

Comment: password_verify should work - are you sure the hash you are using as test case is from "123"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same hashing mechanism and check if your meteor app uses SALT.

https://www.meteor.com/utilities

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_passwords

From their page it appears bcrypt library is used to hash user passwords.

Comment: so, what is the solution here? how to check meteor hashed passwords against php/laravel?